# ios SpriteKit: how to make SKLabelNode object alway on top in a SKView

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skview, sklabelnode

SKView has some SKSpriteNodes and a SKLabelNode. And SKLabelNode alway show some help info text. While SKSpriteNode object moves in SKView and sometimes it will hide the SKLabelNode. Is there any method to make the SKLabelNode always on the top layer of SKView.

The Answer is: set the Zposition of SKView.

Comment: Simply give it a higher zPosition...

Comment: zPosition is set to 0 by default.The positive z axis is projected toward the viewer so that nodes with larger z values are closer to the viewer. Thanks!

Comment: Careful: if you set the zPosition too high it will render behind the person looking at the screen and they won't see it… [\humor]